# Does my 4 month old baby need a visa for United Kingdom

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, filipino-citizens, family

I am British by birth and I have a 4 month old Philippines son.
I wish to bring my son home and after researching my self I need help.
I am needing information as to whether my son needs a visa if so how long and how much?

Comment: Are you planning on applying for a British passport for him? https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizenship/born-outside-the-uk-or-stateless

Comment: Are you a British citizen by descent or otherwise than by descent? Is the travel a visit, or a long term move?

Comment: Have you checked if your son fulfills the requirements of being a UK citizen by birth? Then you just need to get him a passport at the nearest UK embassy.

Comment: Did you give birth to your son or have you adopted him?

Comment: @phoog OP could be the father.

Comment: @mkennedy indeed.  I think I misread the name as some commonly female name.  In that case would it matter whether he was married to the mother?  I know that this can be significant in some cases but I don't remember whether it is under current UK law.  There's also the possibility of a child born to a married woman where the father is not the mother's husband.

Answer (score 2):

To enter the UK without a visa, your son must have a UK passport, or a passport from a country that's allowed visa-free entry to the UK.* If he has a passport from a country that isn't visa-free for the UK, he will need a UK visa.

It would clearly be helpful to this process if you (on his behalf) had [established his British citizenship](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1_drym8LmAhWDIDQIHW2xBp8QFjAGegQICxAd&url=https%3A%2F%2Fiasservices.org.uk%2Fbritish-citizenship%2Fbritish-citizenship-for-child-born-abroad%2F&usg=AOvVaw2YkI8WwfM4gTCfCtDq2ozw) and [secured for him a UK passport](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-child-passport). If you cannot establish his British nationality, you can re-start your research on the visa issue on [this UK government webpage](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

*There are some minor exceptions to this statement. For example, a British citizen who has lost his passport overseas can obtain a Travel Authorization document from a UK consulate abroad that will serve *in lieu* of a passport and permit one-way travel to the UK. Because your son has never had a UK passport, the UK Consulate in the Philipines will not issue him a Travel Authorization.

Comment: Do you have any tips regarding air travel with babies? Is there any fast track at UK immigrations?

Comment: The computer programmer in me would note that the UK is also "a country that's allowed visa-free entry to the UK."

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I don't. And remember the challenge is not just at UK Immigration, but at the airline check-in where the journey begins.